# Handling then-able Java-script function inside for loop to fill an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get an array of JSON objects from my database(MongoDB) by reforming the result that I get from the database and fill that data in an array.
This is the Data Model :

```
var TransferSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Time: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
Type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
User: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
Amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
Sex: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
Age: {
    type: String,
    required: true 
},
Profession: {
    type: String,
    required: true 
},
Agence: {
    type: String,
    required: true 
}
```

I want to get data like this  :

```
   Data : [{
            day : "1-1-2020",
            total_amount : 50,
            Agence : "X"
    },
        {
          day : "1-1-2020",
          total_amount : 50,
          Agence : "X" 
        }
```

So I tried to implement this NodeJS code

```
var Data = []
function getCurrentMonth(i) {
  return moment().subtract(i, "months").format("YYYY-MM");
}

async function getFrequencebyDay()  {
  for (i=0;i<8;i++){
    await  Transfer.find({
      Time: {
        $gte: getCurrentDay(i) + "T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        $lte: getCurrentDay(i) + "T23:00:00.000+00:00",
      },
    })
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
      //Make my Json object after reforming my results
      //and nesting them 
    }) 
  }
}
```

but when I console log the results I get an empty array. I think that I get an empty result because the mishandling of the .then inside the for loop

Comment: Could you provide getCurrentDay function code?

Comment: @PaulRumkin I've added it

Comment: Create an async function that you use for logging in the then scope.

Comment: @PatricNox i didnt understand you

Comment: I meant to put `console.log(results)` in its own async function

Comment: does `console.log(await  Transfer.find({}))` provides any output?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with MongoDB in a NodeJS context, but I think your problem comes from promises handling: When working with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you have to chose between the newer [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) method, or the more classic `.then().catch()` one.

Here, you're using both: there's an await before `Transfer.find`, and a `.then()` after. This probably causes the `.then()` to be empty, since the promise has already been handled by the `await`.

You have two possibilities:

```
function getFrequencebyDay()  {
  for (i=0;i<8;i++){
    Transfer.find({
      Time: {
        $gte: getCurrentDay(i) + "T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        $lte: getCurrentDay(i) + "T23:00:00.000+00:00",
      },
    })
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
      //Make my Json object after reforming my results
      //and nesting them 
    }) 
  }
}
```

or:

```
async function getFrequencebyDay()  {
  for (i=0;i<8;i++){
    let results = await Transfer.find({
      Time: {
        $gte: getCurrentDay(i) + "T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        $lte: getCurrentDay(i) + "T23:00:00.000+00:00",
      },
    })
    console.log(results);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried those two possibilities and i get the same result

Comment: then I'm afraid we'll need more of your code to help. Do you have reference for this `Transfer` object ? or even better a repo with a minimal functionning example